# JAVA license plate number

Tags: java, regex

I need to write a program that reads 3 letters and 3 digits from the user and inserts them into an array (in this format: `ABC-123`).

How can I make a loop that asks the user to enter 5*3 letters and 5*3 digit until he answers correctly (only 3 letters after "please enter 3 letters" and only 3 digits after "please enter 3 digits"?

My code so far:

```
    package bmm;

    import java.util.*;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;
    public class bmm {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
            String[] letter = new String[5];
            int[] number = new int[5];
            int db = 0;
            do {
                for (int i = 0; i < letter.length; i++) {

                    System.out.println("3 letters please:");
                    letter[i] = scr.nextLine();
                    if (Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", letter[i]) == false || letter[i].length() != 3) {
                        System.out.println("not letters or too short/long");
                    } else {
                        db++;
                    }
                }
            } while (letter[db].length() != 3 && Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", letter[db]) != true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your biggest problem is in how you handle the loops; you have them nested in the wrong order.

You have a `do` loop that is supposed to loop until the input string matches the requirements.  *Inside* that loop, you have a `for` loop that goes through the array (I assume the user is supposed to enter 5 valid license numbers?).  Since the loop that goes from 0 to 4 is inside, the program goes through the entire array before the condition at the end of the `do` is checked.  That isn't what you want.  You want to start by entering `letter[0]`, and then continue doing input until the user enters a valid input for `letter[0]`.  Then you continue by entering `letter[1]`, looping until the input is valid, and so on.  I think that's what you want to do, right?  To do things this way, the loop that does the checking must be inside the `for` loop.  In addition, you've defined two variables that are supposed to indicate array indexes, `i` and `db`, and your program seems confused about which one it's using.  You don't need both.

Here's what the *inside* loop should look like, approximately:

```
do {
    System.out.println("3 letters please:");
    letter[i] = scr.nextLine();
    if (Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", letter[i]) == false || letter[i].length() != 3) {
        System.out.println("not letters or too short/long");
    } 
} while (letter[i].length() != 3 && Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", letter[i]) != true);
```

Except that `&&` here is wrong.  You used `||` above; why should they be different?  In fact, you shouldn't repeat the condition twice.  You can save the result of the match in a `boolean` variable:

```
boolean invalid;
do {
    System.out.println("3 letters please:");
    letter[i] = scr.nextLine();
    invalid = (Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", letter[i]) == false || letter[i].length() != 3);
    if (invalid) {
        System.out.println("not letters or too short/long");
    } 
} while (invalid);
```

and now you don't have to worry about making a mistake when you type the expression twice.

I wouldn't write the code exactly like this (you never need to say `== false` or `== true` for a boolean expression, and I'd use `break` instead of a `boolean` variable), but I hope this should be enough to get you going.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! You solved my problem and helped me to understand this dowhile loop. Im a newbie, so sorry for the retarded question. Anyways, you left me hanging:) How would you solve this if not this way?

Comment: I'm not sure there's anything major I would change.  You can say `!Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", letter[i])` instead of `Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", letter[i]) == false`.  And you could get rid of the boolean, use `while(true) { ... }` as the loop, and say `if (!Pattern.matches(...) || letter[i].length() != 3) { System.out.println(...); } else { break; }` which will leave the loop as soon as the input is valid.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're asking or doing.  If you are giving the user 5 chances to enter ONE license plate number, there is no need to store them in an array letter[], unless you want to keep wrong answers.  db and i seem to be conflicting in what they do.  Also you are not matching any numbers.  You probably want to separate out the loops to make things clearer.  Here's an example of getting a single plate number in a method:

```
public static String getPlate(){
    Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);

    int tries = 0;
    boolean validResponse = false;

    while (tries<5 || validResponse){
        String response = scr.nextLine();
        if (Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", response) == false || response.length() != 3) {
            validResponse = false;
        } else {
            return response;
        }
        tries++;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then when you need a plate, you can call it:

```
String plate = getPlate();
```

and fill up your array as needed.